# Yii2 : How to create Modal Window within foreach?

Tags: php, yii2-basic-app

I used foreach for displaying values from database with action field within tree structure. Like below ,

```
 if($charTaCount > 0){
    echo "<div>Turn Around";
       echo "<div><table>";                       
         echo "<tr><th>User Name</th><th>File</th><th>Action</th</tr>";
            foreach ($charTaAll as $charTa){
              echo "<tr><td>$charTa->user</td>"
                     . "<td><a onClick=javascript:window.location='$charTa->url'>Link</a></td>"                                    
                     . "<td><a onClick=javascript:window.location='/path/to/action/ok?id2=$charTa->id'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span></a>&nbsp;" 
                     . "<a class='test' href='/path/to/action/feedback?id=$charTa->id'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tasks'></span></a>&nbsp;</td>"
                     . "</td></tr>";
           }
      echo "</table></div>";
   echo "</div>";
 }
```

In this, how to create modal window for href='/path/to/action/feedback>id=$charTa->id'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use one modal for all rows.
   Add static attrs to button:
   `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-id"` 
   and generate one modal block:

and replace content for each rows by JQuery.

2. You can add modal windows with content for each rows in foreach.
   Add dinamics attrs to button:

   ... data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-'.$row_id.'" ...

And add in each rows modal window block:

```
echo '<div class="modal fade" id="modal-'.$row_id.'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery, bootstrap to complete this task. Write button click event in jquery and access id and create modal using bootstrap modal

Comment: I tried but getting modal window for first value in the loop.